# How would i go about simulating the fetch stage of a CPU?

Tags: c++, logic, machine-code

So I'm trying to build a program that simulates an 8-bit CPU in C++, and I'm specifically hitting a roadblock on the part where the CPU fetches the next instruction from memory. (not a real CPU, though the instruction set is loosely based on the 6502) This project is purely a computer engineering exercise, which is a subject that I'm not too familiar with.

I have a function `fetchInst(location)` which takes a memory address, (as in an index for the CPU's simulated memory array, not an actual C++ pointer), and returns a struct object that includes the opcode, addressing mode, and, ideally, a list of operands that are relevant to the instruction.

The issue is that each operation requires a different set of operands, and even that depends on the addressing mode. For example, one instruction might only require a single 8-bit integer as the operands, while another might requires as many as two 8-bit integers and a 16-bit integer for its operands, for example.

essentially, the organization of the instruction's arbitrary binary data, like

```
1011011110101000100011100011011011100001
```

into an array of discrete operands that are easier to work with, like

```
  opcode     operand
[10110111], [10101000]
```

or

```
  opcode     operand     operand         operand
[10110111], [10101000], [10001110], [0011011011100001]
```

depending on the operation and addressing mode is something i have no idea how to do efficiently.

Theoretically, the naive solution would be giving the execution function the largest number of bytes after the opcode that it could ever need (probably around 5),
and relying on the execution code to parse the operands out of the raw byte data it is given, which could work, but i highly doubt its the most efficient solution.

Comment: Break it down into separate functions: fetching the right number of bytes, parsing into operands, executing the result.  Don't worry about efficiency.  Number of bytes should be a pretty simple table lookup for any 8-bit CPU that I've seen.

Comment: Yeah, having it separated into 3 separate functions is what I'm doing, its just how to actually go about doing those first and second steps that is confusing me. The problem with a lookup table is that it grows extremely complicated if you have to account for the fact that the lengths of operands change with the addressing mode.

Comment: Not sure about your case, but opcode + address mode is all in the first byte of the instruction for 6502, so just a 256-byte table.